# When I shift the 2D-array to the left more than twice it replaces one of the numbers

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, shift

```
public static void shiftLeft(int[][] array,int num, int rowSel) {
    int m = array[rowSel].length;
    int temp = array[rowSel][0];
    for (int k=0; k<m-num; k++){
        array[rowSel][k] = array[rowSel][k+num];
    }
    array[rowSel][m-num] = temp;


    System.out.println("Final array: ");
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++){
            System.out.printf("%4d",array[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Example output

```
Enter number of rows: 
4

Enter number of columns: 
4

ArrayA

12  12  10  14
18   5   2   0
16   1   2   2
17  15   6  15

Which row [0..3] do you want to shift to the left?

2

How many times?

3

Final array: 

12  12  10  14
18   5   2   0
2   16   2   2
17  15   6  15
```

Notice the 3rd line changes the 1 to a 2

Comment: Try calling shiftLeft(array, 1, rowSel) num times - does that work?  If so, then something is wrong with your logic where `num` > 1.

Comment: It ends up shifting it to the right
edit: oops. I looked at it wrong. Yes it does work when changed to 1

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

First, this:

```
for (int k=0; k<m-num; k++){
    array[rowSel][k] = array[rowSel][k+num];
}
```

Your loop termination condition `k<m-num` is bad.  For your case: m=4, num=3, so this only evaluates once, as it is effectively `k<1`.

Also: you are overwriting the row you as you are copying... so later copies risk copying the same numbers again.  I think you need something like this:

```
int[] savedRow = new int[m];
for (int k=0; k<m; k++){
    savedRow[k] = array[rowSel][k];
}
for (int k=0; k<m; k++){
    array[rowSel][k] = savedRow[(k+num)%m];
}
```

Comment: Whats savedRow supposed to represent?

Comment: I updated answer to clarify; savedRow is like your original `int temp` , but temporarily holds the whole row.  Please be sure to upvote my answer if it helps, and select it as "best" if it is!